# Can't sum a vector of integers using for loop c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, vector, sum

I am writing a function that takes a vector of integers as input, and iterates through the vector to obtain the maximum and minimum values in the vector, as well as the sum. The maximum possible integer in the argument vector is 1000000000.

```
void miniMaxSum(vector<long> arr) {
    long sum = 0;
    long min = 1000000000;
    long max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
        sum += arr[i];
        if (arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Using the following input vector as argument:

```
vector<long> x = {793810624,895642170,685903712,623789054,468592370 };
```

The sum is a negative number: -827229366

Comment: You don't need `vector` to show the error.  This is obviously an integer overflow problem, all due to the addition.  Try `int64_t` instead of `long` as the type.

Comment: Also, your code is broken if all of those numbers in the vector are negative.  You will not get the correct maximum value.

Comment: You should first test with something you can work out by yourself, eg 1,2,3,4,5 which you can work out is 15.

Comment: You could initialise `sum`, `min` and `max` to `arr[0]` and then run the loop from `i = 1` to the end of the array.  That avoids the issue with an all negative array.  You function does not output either `min` or `max`, only `sum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long` is usually a 32-bit type on most operating systems (at least 32-bit). So the maximum value it can hold is `2,147,483,647`.

The sum of your numbers is `3,467,737,930`. So it overflows.

Consider using `unsigned long` or `long long` (at least 64 bits) or `unsigned long long` for larger numbers. Or you could even use `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` to get the biggest integer that is supported.

Comment: Or better yet `int64_t` or `uint64_t`, as they specifically state the bitness that is being used.